# WebRTC app not working on firefox

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I have a very tremendous issue in my app. App is using webrtc to create video connection between two people. 
Currently the app it's in the test phase.
Everything is working fine on Chrome, but on Firefox there is a strange issue.

When the second Peer connects I receive this error:

```
Error adding ice candidate for pcInvalidStateError: setRemoteDescription needs to called before addIceCandidate
```

I know that the error message seems to be clear, but how it's possible that on Chrome this error does not exist?
I mean, maybe there is a bigger issue, not completely depending on this error message.

Do you have any ideas or solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

A part from [WebRTC doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/setRemoteDescription): (See `Deprecated Exception` section)

> Deprecated exceptions
>
> **When using the deprecated callback-based version** of
>   setRemoteDescription(), **the following exceptions may occur**:
>
> **InvalidStateError**  The connection's signalingState is "closed",
>   indicating that the connection is not currently open, so negotiation
>   cannot take place.

You should check you are not using deprecated callback version of this function. Also you should keep an eye on `signalingState` of the peer connection.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm using the version with `then`, `catch` so its okay if I good understand what the deprecated version means

Comment: do you have more than one overloads of "setRemoteDescription" ?

Comment: Well yes, Firstly I'm using setRemoteDescription when the 2nd peer connects to establish a connection. 
Then I'm using setRemoteDescription onAnswer and onOffer while Negotiating